# Python itertools: Cartesian product with filtering of empty strings

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm writing a script to call a program with all possible command-line arguments. Some of these arguments can be not present. Attempt #1:

```
args1 = ['program.exe']
args2 = ['1', '5', '']
args3 = ['--foo', '']
for args in itertools.product(args1, args2, args3):
    args = [arg for arg in args if arg != '']
    subprocess.call(list(args))
```

Is there another way to get these permutations without having to manually filter out the empty string? Things break if I just leave it in the argument list. I mean, my approach works, but I feel like there would be some more built-in way to handle this. Although reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891032/python-cartesian-product-and-conditions) is making me think that's less likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to look a bit cleaner you could use the built-in filter() function.

```
args = filter(lambda x: not x, args)
```

Or if you don't like the lambda

```
args = filter(not_empty, args)

----

def not_empty(x):
    return not x
```

I don't know of a way to do this with just `itertools` functions.

Comment: You can use `None` in place of `not_empty` with `filter`.